# Self signed SSL key generation for a specific application

Tags: ssl, openssl, client-server, ca, diffie-hellman

I am trying to generate the re-generate the expired keys in [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4822).

I followed the steps in [this link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zmiller/ca-howto/), but the certificates did not work.

The required certificates are as follows:

```
client.pem
dh1024.pem
root.pem
server.pem
```

In my understanding dh is a diffie-hellman key. root.pem is used to sign client and server certificates. Anybody know's a good tutorial on generating the keys in the above manner so I can regenerate they keys for the example in [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4822).

Comment: Keys don't expire. Certificates expire. You don't have to regenerate keys, you just have to re-sign the certificate. "The certificates did not work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Currently I don't have the keys. Only the .pem files, so I think I will have to re-generate the keys too?

Comment: If you don't have the keys you have nothing at all. You'll have to start again.

Comment: I followed the tutorial here - http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zmiller/ca-howto/ but was not able to get certificates working. What different commands should I issue to get the correct certificates?